# Android post innexplicable error

Tags: android, eclipse, post

I am trying to POST a user and password to a php file situated on a remote server and android gives me an exception that I do not understand.

I mean, my code looks like this:

```
String url_connect = "http://myhost.com/mylogin.php";
Boolean result_back;

public boolean loginstatus(String username ,String password ) {
  int logstatus=-1;
  ArrayList<NameValuePair> postparameters2send= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uzer",username));
  postparameters2send.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass",md5(password)));
  JSONArray jdata=post.getserverdata(postparameters2send, url_connect);
  ... more code here
}
```

and the error in LogCat

```
Error in http connection: java.net.UnknownHostException: myhost.com
```

But the problem is... If I copy the entire url_connect string declared above, and paste it into a browser... it works just fine. Why does Eclipse throw me this error?

How can I fix this?

My AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mysoft.mydualscreenpro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mysoft.mydualscreenpro.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mysoft.mydualscreenpro.MyNewScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_new_screen" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you added the INTERNET permission in `AndroidManifest` file, otherwise Android won't let your application access the internet and will throw that excception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your app has permission to access the internet.  When a user installs the app, they will see that your app will have access to the internet, and choose whether they still want to use enter code here it.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It should go outside of the `<application>` tag and inside the `<manifest>` tag along with any other permissions you may use, as shown below.

```
</application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />    
</manifest>
```

There's also a bunch more permissions that you should read about:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html